# Frozen Java Jcomponent

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, repaint, jcomponent

I've got a problem with my Component in Java. The problem is that in my GUI i can't see any changes of my ovals colors. When the OVF flag is set to false they should be white, and when the flag OVF is set to true, they should be red. But when i starting my program, the flag OVF is set to fasle and all of ovals are white - that's good. When the flag is changing to true, the ovals are still white. I try to add repaint() function, but the white ovals are still blinking, without change color. Here is my code of class Komponent:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Komponent extends JComponent {

    Counter counter3;

    public Komponent() {
        counter3 = new Counter();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D dioda = (Graphics2D) g;
        int x1 = 85;
        int x2 = 135;
        int x3 = 35;
        int x4 = 185;
        int x5 = 235;
        int x6 = 88;
        int x7 = 138;
        int x8 = 38;
        int x9 = 188;
        int x10 = 238;
        int y_ob = 0;
        int y = 3;
        int width_ob = getSize().width / 9;
        int height_ob = getSize().height - 1;
        int width = (getSize().width / 9) - 6;
        int height = (getSize().height - 1) - 6;
        if (counter3.OVF == true) {
            dioda.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            dioda.fillOval(x1, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x2, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x3, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x4, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x5, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.setColor(Color.RED);
            dioda.fillOval(x6, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x7, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x8, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x9, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x10, y, width, height);
            repaint();
        }
        if (counter3.OVF == false) {
            dioda.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            dioda.fillOval(x1, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x2, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x3, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x4, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.fillOval(x5, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
            dioda.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            dioda.fillOval(x6, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x7, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x8, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x9, y, width, height);
            dioda.fillOval(x10, y, width, height);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new Komponent();
    }
}
```

Please, help (sorry for my English) ;)

Comment: Give us the code where you're changing the OVF flag to true.

Comment: why a new thread, whats wrong with last one, btw there is asked for SSCCE, ....... your effort.equalsIgnoreCase(potential good answers)

Comment: It is not problem witch changing OVF to true, because when the OVF flag is true in my GUI I've got a label, and when the OVF is true, the visible of label is set to true - and it's works.

Answer (score 3):

1. override `getPreferredSize`, then coordinates will be `getHeight`/`Weight`
2. Custom painting in Swing is done by using `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`instead of public `void paint(Graphics g) {`
3. first code line inside `paintComponent` should be `super.paintComponent(g);`
4. start `Swing Timer` for periodical `repaint()` if needed
5. no reason to create all elements on runtime, put all element to the `array` (two arrays in your case), inside `paintComponent` only loop inside array

EDIT (rest is up to you, point 1st and 5th)

[image] . . [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Komponent {

    private boolean counter3 = false;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private Timer timer;
    private CustomComponents cc1 = new CustomComponents();

    public Komponent() {
        counter3 = false;
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 10));
        frame.add(cc1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1500, updateCol());
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("Hello World") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean bol = counter3;
                if (bol) {
                    counter3 = false;
                    cc1.repaint();
                } else {
                    counter3 = true;
                    cc1.repaint();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    class CustomComponents extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D dioda = (Graphics2D) g;
            int x1 = 85;
            int x2 = 135;
            int x3 = 35;
            int x4 = 185;
            int x5 = 235;
            int x6 = 88;
            int x7 = 138;
            int x8 = 38;
            int x9 = 188;
            int x10 = 238;
            int y_ob = 0;
            int y = 3;
            int width_ob = getSize().width / 9;
            int height_ob = getSize().height - 1;
            int width = (getSize().width / 9) - 6;
            int height = (getSize().height - 1) - 6;
            if (counter3) {
                dioda.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                dioda.fillOval(x1, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x2, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x3, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x4, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x5, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.setColor(Color.RED);
                dioda.fillOval(x6, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x7, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x8, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x9, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x10, y, width, height);
            } else {
                dioda.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                dioda.fillOval(x1, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x2, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x3, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x4, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.fillOval(x5, y_ob, width_ob, height_ob);
                dioda.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                dioda.fillOval(x6, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x7, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x8, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x9, y, width, height);
                dioda.fillOval(x10, y, width, height);
            }
            dioda.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Komponent komponent = new Komponent();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to do it right now, and after it I tell you my results. Thank you

Comment: I've done 2nd and 3rd point (1st and 4th I will do it later - it's no connection with my problem) but it still not working. I don't understand 5th point - is it most important to solve my problem?

Comment: but it still not working. == SSCCE, 5th point not isn't important, this point is about coding concept

Comment: What is SSCCE and effort.equalsIgnoreCase? What should i do with it? I'm sorry but my English is not so good

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase == joke,  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JComponent, demonstraded a.m. issue, you question contains two issues, code posted here and bothering with how works in your case, how rest of Swing GUI is coded

Comment: Ehh.. I'm trying to do this for 2 days, I think I tried to do everything, including that when the OVF==true the panel in my GUI (witch added component) is set to Visible, and when OVF==false, the panel Visiblity is set to false. It's working, but I don't expecting this.

Answer (score 2):

You call repaint() inside your paint()-method? which calls the paint() method again, which may call repaint() again, and so on....

Not sure, if this is your problem, but i think you call repaint at the wrong place.

Comment: i tried to add in my class GUI line:
komponent2.repaint();
when i'm pressing the button COUNT UP (and if it's count to 10 then OVF=true) but it not works

Comment: Too bad, i have no idea, what else could do the trick... Maybe what mKorbel suggested? sounds pretty good. sorry for wasting your time on trying my solution

Comment: That is what we try to do here. ;-)